# Oozie solution to execute a query and get results back from sql & Hive

Tags: sql, hiveql, oozie, sqoop2, oozie-workflow

I am trying to solve the below problem using oozie. Any suggestions about solution are much appreciated.

Back ground :  I had developed a code to import data from SQL database using (oozie - Sqoop import)  and done some transformation and loaded the data to Hive.   Now I need to do a count check between SQL and Hive for reconciliation

Is there any way I can do that using oozie.

I am thinking about executing sql query using "sqoop eval"  and hive query using "hive action"  from oozie ,  but I am wondering how can we get the results back to oozie / capture the results after the query execution .

Once the results are available I need to do a reconciliation in subsequent action

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I had implemented it using a py-spark action , by executing sqoop eval and Hive Dataframe counts.  Its working fine.